# switch case chage button dataset atrribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a start & the stop button, when I click stop button I need to change the data attribute value to stop, then click again to switch the button console to get 'start', but now I'm totally confused about how I make it work! make one function or two.

```js
let stopbutton = document.querySelector(".button");
let stoper = stopbutton.dataset.slideStop //value 'start'
stopbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  stopbutton.dataset.slideStop = 'stop';
  switch (stoper) {
    case 'start': {
      console.log('start'); 
    } break;
    case 'stop': {   
      console.log('stop'); /* */
    } break;
  }
});
```

```html
<button data-slide-stop="start" class="button">stop</button>
```

Comment: What you have is a very basic state machine with 2 states (`started`, `stopped`) and 2 transitions (`started -stop-> stopped`, `stopped -start-> stopped`) (see https://deniskyashif.com/2019/11/20/a-practical-guide-to-state-machines/ for more). The problem with your code is that when you don't set `started` state after transitioning from `stopped` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned a value to 'stoper' at the start and never changed it:

```
let stoper = stopbutton.dataset.slideStop //value 'start'
```

Change that line to:

```
let stoper;
```

to declare the variable globally.
And then you need to check the button's dataset EVERY time it is clicked, so in the 'click' listener you need to add at the beginning:

```
stoper = stopbutton.dataset.slideStop
```

and then alternate its dataset value like that:

```
stopbutton.dataset.slideStop = stoper === 'stop' ? 'start' : 'stop';
```

Full code will look like that:

```js
let stopbutton = document.querySelector(".button");
let stoper;
stopbutton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  stoper = stopbutton.dataset.slideStop;
  stopbutton.dataset.slideStop = stoper === 'stop' ? 'start' : 'stop';
  switch (stoper) {
  case 'start': {
    console.log('start'); 
  } break;
  case 'stop': {   
    console.log('stop'); /* */
  } break;
}
});
```

```html
<button data-slide-stop="start" class="button">stop</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alternate between `"start"` and `"stop"` for both the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [text content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the button by checking the current value of each and setting it to the opposite, like this:

```js
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener(
  "click",
  ({ currentTarget: btn }) => {
    const toggle = (value) => value === "stop" ? "start" : "stop";
    btn.textContent = toggle(btn.textContent);
    btn.dataset.slideStop = toggle(btn.dataset.slideStop);
    console.log("btn.dataset.slideStop:", btn.dataset.slideStop);
  },
);
```

```html
<button data-slide-stop="start" class="button">stop</button>
```